# Is there a way to apply sklearn models trained on sentence-level data to make predictions on longer documents?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to figure out if I can train on annotated data for sentiment analysis where each data point is a sentence and then use those models on much larger data. When I tried to I got the following error:
Error when I tried a decision tree model:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 30 and input n_features is 75000
```

And this one was from trying an SVM:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 75000 should be equal to 30, the number of features at training time
```

Note: 30 is the length of all the tokenised sentences that were used to train, and 75000 is the length of the larger documents on which I'm trying to make predictions.

And here's the code to make the predictions, just in case, although this is very standard so it doesn't mean much I feel. I can also paste the code for the training, but again I don't believe it is relevant to my question:

```
y_test_pred_10k = model_dt.predict()X_test10k
svm_predictions_test_10k = SVM.predict(X_test10k)
```

I'm not sure what options there are if any to make this work other than padding the sentences to be of a length of 75000, but that seems like it wouldn't be a good idea. Are there any other choices?

Comment: features are independent of the data size ( it could depend though). you have to reshape data to fit your network input

Comment: In sentiment analysis, aren't the features the tokenised, numeric representations of the words themselves though? The sklearn models seem to take the number of words as the features when I use .fit() on them with the training data. I'm familiar with creating your own features in other kinds of classification, like using mean reversion as a feature for finance data, but for sentiment I thought it was always the words. Is there another way to do this? I could reshape the training data to match the data to predict on but that would mean padding 30 word length sentences with 1000s of 0s. Thanks!